# Google Map won't show in Phonegap iOS App

Tags: html, ios, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I have an PhoneGap iOS app and have this HTML that won't show the map in the app.  I see the map perfectly in Safari or FF but not in the app.  How can I get this to work?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
                    var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(37.654,-77.980);
                        var myOptions = {
                                        zoom: 12,
                                        center: initialLocation,
                                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            });
</script>   
</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="content">   
    <!--images go here -->
    <div class="img_shadow" style="padding:4px;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:130px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>      
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PhoneGap has a whitelist system for external URLs/Hosts.

From the wiki:

> Also, the latest code has the new white-list feature. If you are
>   referencing external hosts, you will have to add the host in
>   PhoneGap.plist under the "ExternalHosts" key. Wildcards are ok. So if
>   you are connecting to "http://phonegap.com", you have to add
>   "phonegap.com" to the list (or use the wildcard "*.phonegap.com" which
>   will match subdomains as well).

Your code snippet above has a few external hosts in it:

- maps.google.com
- code.jquery.com

Perhaps try adding "*" to ExternalHosts to start with to make sure that isn't the problem, then add more specific hosts once it's working.

Answer (score 11):

You have to Add everything Google Maps wants to load to the external hosts list.
I added the following and it works fine for me:

- *.google.com
- *.googleapis.com
- *.gstatic.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the hosts, but your the "*.googleapis.com" solution worked. But the map still didn't appear because I hadn't an API key and this solved my problem. Hope it helps you because in your code you don't have an API key.

Comment: API keys are no longer required in the Google Maps Javascript-API.