# Open native maps app from phonegap

Tags: iphone, google-maps, cordova

Is there phonegap solution for opening the native maps app centred on a location or with a route displayed?

Comment: are you talking about opening the maps application or simply a maps view built into your phone gap application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out, just use window location and the device intercepts it...

```
$('#map').bind('tap', function(){
    var url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?';
    url += 'q=[place_name]';
    url += '&near=';
    url += [lat];
    url += ',';
    url += [lon];
    url += '&z=15';
    // open the native maps app by calling window location
    window.location = url;
});
```

Comment: This worked a treat, although I had to add maps.google.com to the whitelist in the PhoneGap.plist before it worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146231/google-map-wont-show-in-phonegap-ios-app

Comment: Its about as native as everything else on phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

To open iOS6 Maps app, use `maps.apple.com` domain.

See:

- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505451/how-to-open-ios-6-maps-from-mobile-website)
- [Apple Schema URL Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1)