# How to open iOS 6 maps from a mobile website?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, mobile

I have a mobile website that I've had a link to open Google maps app from within my website. Now however with the new version of ios6, the native version of google maps is no more and now the link opens to a safari based google maps. I'd rather have this open in a native Apple maps app. How can I do this?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using the previous Google domain `maps.google.com` you use `maps.apple.com`. This will remain compatible with older devices running 5.x and below.

It looks like this:

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=cupertino
```

Most of the parameters are the same, but see the Apple docs for more details:

[Apple URL Scheme Reference: Map Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)

Answer (score 1):

what do you want ?

open maps web safari or open maps  app ?

try this

```
CLLocation * currentLocation;
NSURL *requestUrl;
CLLocationCoordinate2D storedLocation;


CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { (storedLocation.latitude), (storedLocation.longitude) };

//Bitiş Yeri
CLLocationCoordinate2D end = { ([koordinatX floatValue]), ([koordinatY floatValue]) };

NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f", start.latitude, start.longitude, end.latitude, end.longitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];
```

Comment: This looks like it's for mobile apps, and not websites (what the question is about).