# PhoneGap: Way to call native Google Maps feature?

Tags: google-maps, cordova

Is there a way to use the native iOS Google Maps app from within a PhoneGap/Cordova application? Or do I have to use a JavaScript version? I am trying to feed an address to a map as well as retain the ability for the users to user their GPS to obtain their location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at the plugins on Github ?
There is a Mapkit plugin : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS

You'll still have to request your GPS location using the API (I think)
Of course this might change when Apple Maps in IOS6 comes out.

Comment: Ah awesome! The mapKit one looks like what I need

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite simple way to do this, here is a sample code

```
$("#btnCallMap").click(function(){
      var url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?';
      url += 'q=<your location>;';
      url += '&z=15'
      window.location = url;  
});
```

You could do this from a jquery button click event as shown.

Hope it helped you.

-- Mejo

Comment: Thanks - does this actually invoke the native Google Maps App? Or does it open a JavaScript version? Also, must I install a plugin for this or is it ready with Cordova

Comment: Yes ,this will open the map in Native iPhone map application. If the map application is absent then url will be opened in default browser.

Comment: You don't have to including any other plugin or java script plugins.

Comment: Ah awesome! do you know of any online tutorial for this at all?

Comment: By the way i forgot to say something, you will have to white list maps.google.com in your project.[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146231/google-map-wont-show-in-phonegap-ios-app) is something which is worth reading.

Comment: In PhoneGap 2.3.0, It opens google maps in web only, if i prefix maps: then its opens mobile app. Any help will be appreciated