# Domain whitelist for PhoneGap/Android app w/Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

I'm building a PhoneGap app, targeted for Android now, using Google Maps. If I only whitelist maps.googleapis.com, it doesn't work. The events object isn't there. If I whitelist all domains, it works.

I'd rather not allow access to all domains. What domains other than maps.googleapis.com do I need to allow access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8836591/1775295) answer, you need to whitelist:

- *.google.com
- *.googleapis.com
- *.gstatic.com

Notice that answer was over a year old now so some of the domains might be outdated or missing.  This should get you started though.

Comment: It turns out I could even remove the access to *.google.com and it'd still work.

Comment: Good to know that one isn't necessary

Answer (score 2):

The syntax depends on which version of PhoneGap you are using. See the relevant version of the documentation for details - eg. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

For version 3.1 or greater, the following works for me:

```
<access origin="*://*.googleapis.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.gstatic.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.google.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.googleusercontent.com/*" subdomains="true" />
```